# The Play store link for the beta gives me a 404

Tags: support, status-completed, android-app

I was invited to join the Stack Exchange Android App Alpha Testing group and accepted the invitation. I appear in the group members if I search but the link to the beta app in the Play store only gives me a 404.

https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.stackexchange.marvin

Is there another step I'm missing?

Comment: When you visit the link above does it state that you are a tester? Is it under the correct e-mail address on the link above? If so, wait around 24 hours and the app should show up in the Play Store.

Comment: I got my invitation a week ago. I've tried that link several times since then and each time it returns a 404 error. I've used the beta program in my own app but with the Google Communities option not G+. When I went through communities to the link for my app, it took me to an opt-in page. I was expecting to see the same for the stack exchange app but I'm not seeing that just the 404.

Comment: Are you logged into the same account as your Google+ which is in the Community? It might be messing up due to some Google products not supporting multiple accounts.

Comment: That was it. I used a different browser and had the same issue until I cleared all history and active logins and re-logged into G+. Then the Play store only saw the one account that was authorized to get the beta. Too bad they don't have something better than a 404 to tell that to the user.

Answer (score 4):

For future people finding this via search: Please make sure that you're logged into the same Google account as the Google+ account you used to join the Community for alpha testers.

Comment: Can't upvote, just wanted to say thanks for this! It apparently does not work if you have the testing account as 2nd account added to your google account, it has to be the main account you are logged in as.